# Predicting profit with price variation

Tags: statistics, regression, mathematical-modeling, data-analysis

I am currently working on a high school project that aims to predict profit from X amount of items to Y amount of profit based off a **deviated** sale price. For instance:

I sale 10 cookies for 10 dollars, but on another sale I am able to sell for a higher price per cookie and achieve to sell 10 cookies for 20 dollars. Now say I sell a bulk order for 200 cookies and sale them for 400 dollars, but someone else makes the same order and I sell it to them for only 300 dollars. Essentially the price per cookie deviates in a range of a couple dollars or so, but when trying to use linear regression, the predictions are not even close to accurate. What is the best way to make an averaged prediction when using this type of business model? `

What is the best regression model in order to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for the help.